# How to check if a string matches a specific format?

Tags: java, string

I want to check if a string matches the following format:

```
"00-00"
```

There should be no whitespace in the String, only 2 numbers before the dash and 2 numbers after the dash.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29):

```
str.matches("\\d{2}-\\d{2}")
```

If you're going to be doing this sort of validation a lot, consider pre-compiling the regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}-\\d{2}");  // use a better name, though
```

You can then use `p.matcher(str).matches()`. See the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class for more details.

Comment: And if the pattern was "A-1232-AB"?

Comment: pattern should be `"^\\d{2}-\\d{2}$"`, will you please edit it..